# How to mock method with pointer argument

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, mocking, turtle-mock

Is it possible to mock method that retrieves pointer (or reference) as argument and change pointed object?

I use turtle library - http://turtle.sourceforge.net/ -> A C++ mock object library for Boost. (I know it is not popular library but it can be similar in other libraries).

For example: I need to mock method as:

```
int f(int* x)
{
    *x = new_value;
    return 0;
}
```

Next SUT uses x value in code :(

In expactations I can set what my mock returns. But how about to modified argument?

How to do that?

Comment: Replace `// *x is modified (object pointed by x is modified)` with `*x = new_value;`

Comment: This is method in SUT (System under test). I need to simulate behavior of this method in my test (in expectation).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at calls and returns actions: 
http://turtle.sourceforge.net/turtle/reference.html#turtle.reference.expectation.actions

You can create a helper function in your test that modifies x as you want. Pass x to that function.

```
int function( int* x )
{
    *x = whatever;
    return 0;
}

MOCK_EXPECT(mock->f).calls( &function );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Fake-It](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt) is a simple mocking framework for C++. It supports both GCC and MS Visual C++.
Here is how you stub a method and change the pointed object with FakeIt:

```
struct SomeClass {
    virtual int foo(int * x) = 0;
};

Mock<SomeClass> mock;
When(Method(mock,foo)).AlwaysDo([](int * x) { (*x)++; return 0;});
SomeClass &obj = mock.get();

int num = 0;
ASSERT_EQUAL(0, obj.foo(&num)); // foo should return 0;
ASSERT_EQUAL(1, num);           // num should be 1 after one call to foo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not similar library to turtle. 
I cannot use other library.

Expectation in turtle looks like:

    MOCK_EXPECT(SomeClass.x)
        .once()     
        .with(&someValue)
        .returns(0);